# How to add Outlook shared mailbox with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to create a script to, in one 'user step', add a shared mailbox to Outlook, set it as the default, and load the encryption certificates for it. The script needs to be run from a CD on the User's account, not Exchange or Admin. Unfortunately, my Google-fu is failing me and I can't figure out how to use PowerShell to add the shared mailbox to Outlook.

We use PKI credentials to log into Outlook, so manual additions are just entering the shared mailboxes e-mail address and selecting our PKI certificate.

Would y'all kindly point me in the right direction here? If PowerShell isn't the best option, I can learn another option, however I can't install additional software.

Note: I'm aware 'auto-mapping' mailboxes exists, however it specifically doesn't work the same as the 'add an account' feature, for some reason.